# Formatar saída do select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com um problema para formata uma coluna no gridview, esta coluna recebe três valores do banco concatenado,  o utlimo valor podendo  ser null, caso o valor seja null tem com não apresentar o ultimo traço que separa o valor 2 do valor 3.

```
SELECT TOP(20)  IdItem, IdComanda, 
                       (convert(varchar(10),IdProduto) + '  -  ' + Produto.nomeproduto + ' -  ' + isnull(complemento,'')) as 'Item', 
                       Unid, 
                       Qtde, 
                       isnull(Pessoa.Apelido,'--') as 'Garcon', 
                       idStatusEntrega as 'Status', 
                       dtSolicitacao as 'HrSolicitacao', 
                        dtPreparo as 'HrPreparacao', 
                        Comanda.NrComanda, Comanda.NrMesa
                  FROM ComandaItem 
                 inner join Produto ON produto.ProdId = ComandaItem.IdProduto
                 INNER JOIN Comanda ON ComandaItem.IdComanda = Comanda.Id
                  left join Pessoa ON Pessoa.IDCadastro = ComandaItem.IdVendedor 
                 WHERE (idStatusEntrega = 1)  
                   and (@IdSetorPreparo = 0 or IdSetorPreparo = @IdSetorPreparo) 
                 ORDER BY dtPreparo DESC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dentro da função isnull, basta concatenar ' - ' com o campo complemento.

Quando o campo complemento for null o resultado da concatenação vai ser null.

Vai ficar assim:

```
(convert(varchar(10),IdProduto) + '  -  ' + Produto.nomeproduto + isnull( ' -  ' + complemento,'')) as 'Item'
```

Comment: Eu pensei nisso, mas acho que não funciona. O `isnull` vai verificar o resultado da concatenação, será que ele entende quando é nulo após isso ?

Comment: Funciona sim. Esta resposta está correcta.

Answer (score 0):

E se você usar a função **SUBSTRING**.

```
SUBSTRING (
(
    convert(varchar(10),IdProduto) + 
    ' - ' + Produto.nomeproduto + 
    ' - '  + isnull(complemento,'')),
0, 
LEN(
    (convert(varchar(10),IdProduto) + 
     ' - ' + Produto.nomeproduto + 
     ' - ' + isnull(complemento,'')) -3) as 'Item',
```